# AngularJS validation for the input type 'time' is not working in IE?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement the input type time in my application using AngularJS.

I used:

```
Select a time: <input type="time" name="usr_time">
```

which is working fine in Chrome but not in IE. I want to implement the some validation for the Time pattern: HHMM for the input. i want to show the error message if the user enters a wrong pattern for the time instead of throwing an alert

http://jsfiddle.net/bga7m1b9/136/

Comment: Do you get any JS/console errors in IE when running this code? What version of IE are you running? What version of Angular?

Comment: no i do am getting any error in the console just the functionality itself is not working

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btime%5D) indicate you need a `ng-model` attribute as well. Why not make use of the example code in this link, and adapt to your needs?

Comment: @halfer This helped me alot thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from your "question" what you're actually asking, but for anything time related I find using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to be incredibly helpful!

If you want us to debug your issue try adding a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with something like [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/) or [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).